# What is a good website monitoring service/program for monitoring side-projects?

Tags: monitoring

I know this is a frequently-discussed topic, but I've read multiple other questions and haven't found anything relevant. I want a website uptime monitoring service or software for my side-projects, so cost is a primary factor.

My requirements are:

1. Free for ~10ish sites.
2. Frequent HTTP uptime checks (15 seconds to a minute between checks).
3. Nice UI.
4. Email alerts.

I haven't managed to find a service like this, but I don't mind setting up an open-source service. However, my requirements there are:

1. Lightweight in RAM/CPU usage.
2. Easy to set up (would ideally only need me to run one process).
3. Few dependencies (ideally only an SQLite database).
4. Basic web UI (just showing a graph, I don't even need web configuration).

Anything I've seen fails at least one of the above criteria, usually the processes and dependencies ones. Most packages (Nagios, Munin, Zabbix, etc) seem to be enterprise-grade with full monitoring, but I just want a simple thing that will email me when one of my projects is down.

Is there something like that, or should I write one?

Comment: Why is this question closed? Sigh, this is where I see StackExchanged being usurped by Quora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually many offers available out there.

Besides most of them propose a minimum of 1min uptime check, there is several free tools.

Here's a comparative list of many products (paid+free), you might find what suits best for you.

https://www.keycdn.com/blog/website-monitoring-tools/

I would personaly consider Monitority a good solution for your needs.

Good search!

Comment: Thank you, that list has many sites I'd never seen before. UptimeRobot looks good, although they only have 5-minute checks. Thanks again!

Comment: Uptime Robot supports 1-minute checks in the Pro Plan -disclaimer: I'm a part of the Uptime Robot team :)-.